# nextflow (groovy) check if item in Channel list

Tags: list, groovy, channel, nextflow

I am struggling to use an if/else on a `containsAll()` statement. It returns the correct `true` `false` value when tested with `println()`, but when put in an `if` statement it seems to always evaluate to true -- see below.

```
def examine_phenotype(pheno){
  condition_values = \
  Channel
        .fromPath(pheno)
        .splitCsv(header: true, sep: ',')
        .map{ row ->

        def condition  = row.condition

        return condition

        }
        .toList().view()

        println(condition_values.containsAll('control'))

        if(condition_values.containsAll('control')){
        exit 1, "eval true"
        }else{
        exit 1, "eval false"
        }
}
```

Console output for two different files, one with 'control' and one without 'control' in the column 'condition', which is the point of the function.

```
[normal, normal, normal, tumor, tumor, tumor]
DataflowInvocationExpression(value=false)
eval true
```

```
[control, control, control, tumor, tumor, tumor]
DataflowInvocationExpression(value=true)
eval true
```

Using `collect()` instead of `toList()` where each item within `condition_values` is enclosed with single quotes did not resolve the issue either. The clue might be in `DataflowInvocationExpression` but I am not up to speed on Groovy yet and am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: `containsAll()` should accept a list, not a string

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I added a list, `check = ['control']` and tried `if(condition_values.containsAll(check)){}` but the same behaviour is observed. I can't check each item against `['control']` during the map phase as it will inevitably fail when it reaches 'tumor'

Comment: can you boil your sample down to the reproducible code, without Channels, nextflow etc.?

Comment: I think I have it working now, I will post the answer shortly. I probably wouldn't have been able to create a reproducible example in groovy so just as well. Thanks for your time and help, have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Testing the conditional within the function was not working, but applying `filter{}` and `ifEmpty{}` was able to produce the desired check:

```
ch_phenotype = Channel.empty()
if(pheno_path){

        pheno_file = file(pheno_path)
        
        ch_phenotype = examine_phenotype(pheno_file)
        ch_phenotype.filter{ it =~/control/ }
                    .ifEmpty{ exit 1, "no control values in condition column"}
}

def examine_phenotype(pheno){
  Channel
        .fromPath(pheno)
        .splitCsv(header: true, sep: ',')
        .map{ row ->

        def condition  =  row.condition
        return condition

        }
        .toList()
}
```